# grid view filters

Tags: asp.net

net application with gridview.Am using filters to filter only one column.Now i want to filter two or more than two columns.How to i set the filters for that..if i give && or|| operators it is showing syntax error..

i given the code as;
"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:booksConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [book]"
            **FilterExpression="UserName Like '{0}%' || Password Like '{0}%'" >**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `OR` instead of `||` in your sql query